# Why doesn't this new Date work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a date with format "MMM. dd HH:mm:ss.nnn". It is rendering it incorrectly in IE and I have spent quite some time and I can't figure out why I can't get this to work.

I know that Date.UTC returns the number of miliseconds in a Date object since Jan 1, 1970. So,

```
var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month[, date[, hrs[, min[, sec[, ms]]]]])
newDate.toString("MMM. dd HH:mm:ss.")+row.timestamp.getMilliseconds();
```

will work.

Example:

```
var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(1950, 10, 10, 10, 09, 09, 100));
row.timestamp_f = newDate.toString("MMM. dd HH:mm:ss."); // Output => Nov. 10 05:09:09.
```

But, I am interating this from a jquey.each function so the date string that I am working with is an ISO 8601: "2013-03-12T15:14:10.483". So, this is what I have in mind.

```
var numMilisecond = Date.parse(row.timestamp);
var newDate = new Date(numMilisecond);
row.timestamp_f = newDate.toString("MMM. dd HH:mm:ss."); // Output => Dec. 31 19:00:00.
```

row.timestamp is from a JSON response

```
{"timestamp":"2013-03-12T15:14:10.483" ...}
```

Why doesn't the code work? Date.parse should return the number of miliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 and then I create a new Date obj and then convert it to string just like the code in the first snipet. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: [Please correct your code to use code blocks instead of blockquotes](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: IE is using [non-standard `toString` behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @zzzBov You might as well have corrected it in the time it took you to post that comment. :-)

Comment: You can just do `new Date(row.timestamp)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat. It won't work with IE. It will return NaN

Comment: @Blazemonger The 2nd code block doesn't work for Firefox as well. I get Dec. 31 19:00:00. with firefox and IE.

Comment: Might I suggest http://momentjs.com/?

Comment: How do I delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Date.toString` shouldn't accept any arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString). If you want a true date-formatting solution, you'll need to use a [plugin](http://momentjs.com/) or roll your own.

```
var shortmonths = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',]; // remaining months are left as an exercise for the reader
row.timestamp_f = shortmonths[newDate.getMonth()]
                  + ". "+newDate.getDate() + " "
                  + newDate.toLocaleTimeString() + ".";
```

Comment: So I am totally embarrassed but it turns out there is a datejs which is doing a lot of magic in the background